# VBA Insert Text below cell1 based on text in cell1 (text/cell variable; in range)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet that is basically a calendar in which I add certain tasks.
Now I would like for excel to add a certain text below a cell if I enter a certain text in this cell.

E.g. If I wrote "Evaluation" in cell A1, the text "Personnel" would appear in cell A2. However, if I wrote "Evaluation" in cell B1, the text "Personnel" would appear in B2 and so on. Furthermore, I would also probably write "Evaluation" in more than one cell and the insertion of "Personnel" should apply to all these cells.

Since it is completely variable where I enter the text ("Evaluation") and all other cells also need to be free, I cannot do it with basic Excel formulas. Thus, I think, VBA is the only way to go.

Unfortunately I have not much experience with VBA, so I would be very glad if you could help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in the worksheet's private code sheet.

```
private sub worksheet_change(byval target as range)
    application.enableevents = false
    dim t as range
    for each t in intersect(target, target.parent.usedrange)
        if lcase(t.value2) = "evaluation" then
            t = "Evaluation"
            t.offset(1, 0) = "Personnel"
        end if
    next t
meh:
    application.enableevents = true
end sub
```